# Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException zend framwork 3

Tags: zend-framework3

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to add a login and a access filter to my project: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/User_Management__Authentication_and_Access_Filtering.html

I've follow all the steps, but it's showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1CCB.png) error.

That's my module code: https://github.com/Nathipg/LoginZf3

I tryed to config the factory at module.config.php but it didn't work

Does anyone have a clue about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

The namespace were wrong at AuthManagerFactory

Comment: My boss order me to delete it, I'm going to update the question later
Thanks for warning me